# NSTrackingArea in Today Extension doesn't provide events

Tags: macos, nstrackingarea, today-extension

I'm working on a Today Extension for the Mac that is supposed to control iTunes. It works and everything, but my UI consists of a square cover art image, overlaid with effect views, which house metadata and controls:

[image: derp]

Now, obviously, it'd be nice if I could somehow make those appear only when I needed to—say, when the mouse cursor was above my extension's view.

As I've dealt with this sort of stuff before, I decided to throw together a little `NSView` subclass that uses `NSTrackingArea` to fire notifications whenever the mouse enters or exists its bounds:

```
/**
 * Sets up the tracking area, for the entire bounds of the view.
 */
- (void) setUpTrackingRect {
    _trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds
                                                 options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect
                                                   owner:self
                                                userInfo:nil];

    [self addTrackingArea:_trackingArea];
}

/**
 * Mouse entry: send TSMouseTrackingViewMouseEntered notification.
 */
- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent *) theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Mouse Enter");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TSMouseTrackingViewMouseEntered
                                                        object:self];
}

/**
 * Mouse exit: send TSMouseTrackingViewMouseLeft notification.
 */
- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent *) theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Mouse Exit");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TSMouseTrackingViewMouseLeft
                                                        object:self];
}
```

(Excerpt from my full code [on GitHub.](https://github.com/tristanseifert/meeper/blob/99bfc1c4fab6b899173289132e14442bcd4af2be/NowPlaying/TSMouseTrackingView.m))

Those `NSLog`s are there for my aid in debugging: they never trigger, despite my cursor moving in and out of the view without issue.

I've been looking through Apple's documentation, and I cannot find anything that explicitly prohibits this sort of thing, or explains why it wouldn't be working. It's a standard `NSView` subclass, in an `NSViewController`, but displayed in Notifications Centre, rather than a standalone app.

Any advice as to why this simple tracking area view isn't working in a Today Extension are appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it only replicates when working with nib files / storyboards. Did you found a solution for this ? A quick comment would help !

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a way around this yet. I talked to an engineer about this at WWDC, and he thought it strange that it didn't work, but suspected it may be because of the way the Notification Centre handles events. Looks like this might be a bug in OS X itself.

Comment: Do you intent to raise a bug ?